# B2C error: ValidateAsync is not supported for Web.TPEngine.Providers.Insights.AzureApplicationInsightsProvider

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have this kind of internal errors inside our Production B2C environment.
Our Insights in the Relaying Party:
[image]

And our AppInsights-Common:
[image]

Exception after 2 or 3 409 business validation exceptions:

[image]

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Please check the following:

When you create an instance of Application Insights in your subscription for required resources, make sure to record the INSTRUMENTATION KEY .
and  ensure the recorded `instrumentation key` is provided and `developer mode to false in the metadata` of technical profile (***Don't enable developer mode in production environments.***)

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="AppInsights-Common">
      <DisplayName>Application Insights</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.Insights.AzureApplicationInsightsProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
     
      <Metadata>
        <!-- The ApplicationInsights instrumentation key, which you use for logging the events -->
        <Item Key="InstrumentationKey">xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx</Item>
        <Item Key="DeveloperMode">false</Item>
        <Item Key="DisableTelemetry ">false</Item>
      </Metadata>

      <InputClaims>
       ....
        </InputClaim Claims>
```

Reference: [***Track user behavior by using Application Insights - Azure AD B2C | Microsoft Docs***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/analytics-with-application-insights?pivots=b2c-custom-policy)

or

Make sure to replace {Your Application Insights Key} with the Application Insights Instrumentation Key that you recorded earlier in the user journey.

*ex:*

> ```
> <UserJourneyBehaviors>
>     <JourneyInsights TelemetryEngine="ApplicationInsights" InstrumentationKey="{Your Application Insights Key}" DeveloperMode="true" ClientEnabled="false" ServerEnabled="true" TelemetryVersion="1.0.0" />
>   </UserJourneyBehaviors>
> ```

***When using  in production environments,i.e; in  the configuration in TrustFrameworkPolicy
Please make sure to set the ***`DeploymentMode`*** attribute to **`Production`**(not developer)***

```
<TrustFrameworkPolicy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06" PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0"
.....
DeploymentMode="Production"
UserJourneyRecorderEndpoint="urn:journeyrecorder:applicationinsights">
```

And change ***`DeveloperMode="false"`*** in userjourney:

```
<JourneyInsights TelemetryEngine="ApplicationInsights" InstrumentationKey="{Your Application Insights Key}" DeveloperMode="false" ClientEnabled="false" ServerEnabled="true" TelemetryVersion="1.0.0" />
```

Please check this doc to [***Troubleshoot custom policies with Application Insights*** - Azure AD B2C | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot-with-application-insights?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) .

- And please note that these detailed logs are collected only when the
  policy is placed in DEVELOPER MODE.
- logs may take a little or some time to populate under app insights.
- Also sometimes the order of userjourney may affect the output, try
  changing it to other step or order .

Comment: This is not working.